# Incrementing on the Initial "Setter" (Attribute Writer-style) Method Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried hard to find another version of this question elsewhere, so apologies if I've missed something... My code snippet here is essentially a reduced, dummy version (for clarity) of Listing 5.7 (pg. 138) from David A. Black's *The Well-Grounded Rubyist (1st Ed.)*, if anyone is familiar.

*Note: I understand that class instance variables are rarely used, but I still want to understand this example.*

The author essentially utilized this design to allow for independent use of an instance counter by subclasses... If the first call to a "setter" method (here, within the "initialize" method) is to increment, what is happening, spelled out? I see that it must be calling the "getter" method, as its conditional assignment functions as intended. Without it, '+' is not recognized as a method. I just don't see how/why. What is happening?

Something like: @thing_count = _________ + num

Is it calling the "getter" method in the blank? Are there alternatives to this design that make it clearer?

Thank you!

```
class Thing
  def self.thing_count
    @thing_count ||= 0
  end

  def self.thing_count=(num)
    @thing_count = num
  end

  def initialize
    self.class.thing_count += 1
  end
end

first = Thing.new
second = Thing.new
third = Thing.new

puts Thing.thing_count

#=> 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to write similar logic that may be easier to understand:

```
class Thing

  @@count = 0  # The double-at-sign makes this a class variable.

  def initialize
    @@count += 1
    puts "count is now #{@@count}"
  end

end

first = Thing.new
=> count is now 1
second = Thing.new
=> count is now 2
third = Thing.new
=> count is now 3
```

The next step is to make the class variable `@@count` accessible outside the instance. To do this, we create accessors:

```
def self.count
  @@count
end

def self.count=(num)
  @@count = num
end
```

Now you can write:

```
Thing.count
=> 3
```

Your code is essentially the same kind of idea:

```
class Thing

  def self.count
    @@count ||= 0
  end

  def self.count=(num)
    @@count = num
  end

  def initialize
    self.class.count += 1
  end

end
```

When you run `Thing.new`, what happens is approximately this:

1. `initialize`
2. Call `self` which returns the instance
3. Call `.class` which returns the `Thing` class.
4. Call `.count`
5. Check the `@@count` variable; if it exists, then return it, otherwise set it to 0 and return it.
6. Call `+= 1` which is typically syntax sugar for `x = x + 1`
7. Add 1 to the value of the `@@count` variable (but does not affect the `@@count` variable)
8. Call `Thing.count=` with the new value.
9. Set `@@count` to the new value.

The code uses this Ruby idiom which sets a default value. Generally, the idiom looks like this for a typical instance variable:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= "bar"
end
```

And for a typical class variable:

```
def self.foo
  @@foo ||= "bar"
end
```

The idiom is a kind of lazy setup. The variable does not exist until the method is called. Each time the method is called, it checks if the variable is defined (then returns it) or not (then sets it).

This is a bit less efficient than doing the setup once.

In my opinion, it is better coding style to explicitly set the class variable to zero once, rather than using the `||=` lazy idiom.

```
class Demo
  @@foo = "bar"
  ...
```

Heads up that the lazy setup idiom fails to work as expected if the value is falsey:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= false  # This will set foo every time
end
```

A solution is to check if the variable is defined:

```
def foo
  defined?(@foo) ? @foo : (@foo = false)
end
```

Another Ruby idiom is to name the method and variable the same name. This is how Ruby does `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, and `attr_accessor`.

For your code, notice that you don't have any `attr_` code, so if you wanted, you could use any variable name you want, such as:

```
def self.count
  @@whatever ||= 0
end

def self.count=(num)
  @@whatever = num
end
```

This can be useful for information-hiding purposes.

The commenter `allielarson1212` makes a good point that the idiom is sometimes called "memoizing". The "memo" idiom typically shows up more like this:

```
def foo
  @foo ||= ... a long time-consuming command ...
end
```

What this does:

1. The first time the method is called, run the command, then keep track of the result
2. The next time the method is called, skip the command and just return the tracked result.

Comment: Thanks very much Joel! I really appreciate your work. I think my confusion essentially came from not completely understanding my version of your #6 above. I think my code is evaluated in three parts there:

(C)[self.class.thing_count =] (A)[self.class.thing_count] (B)[ + 1]
As (C) is the method being called, the class instance variable is SET by evaluating (A), which becomes 0 (initially), doing (B) (adding + 1), and setting (C) to that - - A & B. I apologize for this horrible formatting. I think I now see where (A) is called.

Comment: Ah, I should also note, in case you're curious: The author explains that he uses class instance variables instead of class variables so that a new copy of this construct could be passed to a child class, e.g. class LittleThing could keep its own count without changing the code. I believe class variables would be too 'global', if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

`self.class.thing_count += 1` is calling the method `def self.thing_count` , which is setting `@thing_count` to 0 (if it hasn't been set yet) or is += 1 (adding 1 to the current value of `@thing_count`)  if it has been set previously.

`@thing_count ||= 0` is called memoizing, which just sets `@thing_count` to 0 if it hasn't been defined to be anything yet (which is why `+` wouldn't be recognized, as it'd be calling `+` on nil.)

Comment: Thanks Allie! Great hint on the momoizing term.